# How to use BindView Method with payload argument to update only specified part of list item in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I was going through the documentation of RecyclerView Adapter and found that we have 2 onBindViewHolder methods one with payload list and other without. I assume that the first one is to update a specific part of the item layout.

Does anyone know how that can be achieved? I tried to achieve the same by calling notifyItemChanged method with argument with the view ID that i want to change, but it did not work. Any help will be much appreciated.

My onBindViewHolder with payload is as below:

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(OnAirProductViewHolder viewHolder, int position, List<Object> payloads) {
    ProductData item = mData.get(position);

    int id = -1;
    if(payloads!=null && payloads.size()>0)
        id = (int)payloads.get(0);

    switch (id)
    {
        case R.id.item_current_price:

        viewHolder.currentPrice.setText(item.DefaultEdpItem.DefaultPrice);
        viewHolder.strikedOutPrice.setText(item.DefaultEdpItem.WasPrice);
            break;
        case R.id.item_link_text_line:
            viewHolder.linkText.setText(AppUtils.createdHTMLEncodedString(item.Name));
            break;
    }

}
```

and the way i call it after a network request is as below:

```
mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(mAdapter.getItemIndex(item),R.id.item_current_price);
```

regards,
susheel

Comment: can you add some code that you wrote?

Comment: Hi Kushal , thanks for responding , I have updated my original post with code.